# gem 'paperclip' on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, paperclip

In my system, I am using paperclip gem for users to upload their preferable pictures as a profile pic.

In the local, users can save new picture when changing profile pic. In the remote, of course, they can(I have no idea how paperclip system saves these files.). But when I do "git push heroku master", heroku logs always show me error messages like

```
"ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/members/avatars/000/000/002/thumb/%E5%86%99%E7%9C%9F_(17).JPG"):"
```

And many pictures disappeared although I could see the pic before "git push heroku master".

I guess this is because images uploaded by paperclip system may not be put into "app/assets/images" of the rails folders. Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

☆_form.html.erb(members)

```
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :'picture' %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Email %>
    <%= f.email_field :mail %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit  %>
  </div>
```

☆schema.rb

```
  create_table "members", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "user"
    t.string   "pass"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "mail"
    t.text     "memo"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          :null => false
    t.string   "field"
    t.string   "place"
    t.string   "experience"
    t.string   "url"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "image"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku doesn't allow access to the local filesystem (except for Tempfiles). You'll have to use something like S3 to store your images. Paperclip does this out of the box via either [the S3 Storage module](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3) or [the Fog storage module](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/Fog).

Comment: Here is a good tutorial for S3 integration. It's pretty simple. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3